# open text for only one button, not for all

Tags: python, jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap

Im using `bootstrap collapse` and loops in my template to display data

```
{% for text in imageTitles %}
  <div class="span4 collapse-group">
    <div class="text-center">
      <p><a class="btn btn-md btn-outline-dark btn-square" href="#">Check &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
      <div class="card card-body">
        {{text}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      $('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var $collapse = $this.closest('.collapse-group').find('.collapse');
        $collapse.collapse('toggle');
      });
    </script>
    {% endfor %}
```

when I press the button, then the text for each button is opened, but i need only for one, how to correctly write a function `$('.btn').on('click', function(e)` for correct operation

Comment: do you mean if you click `Check`, your all `{{ text }}` is showing?

Comment: yeah, text for each button at whole page. have many blocks with buttons and hidden text

Comment: your `{{ text }}` is object? or just a text list?

Comment: just a text list

Comment: Then use `{{ forloop.counter }}` to add a `id` in your button and target div. Then use it in your jquery function to find target div from $(this)

Comment: could you pls describe whole code in answer

Comment: I wrote answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{{ forloop.counter }}` to add id for your btn, and target div.

Find your target div by btn's id number.

Also, you don't have to forloop all your script. It's enough for just one.

This is example. you should update for your own.

```
{% for text in imageTitles %}
  <div class="span4 collapse-group">
    <div class="text-center">
      <p><a class="btn btn-md btn-outline-dark btn-square" href="#" id="{{ forloop.counter }}">Check &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample" id="txt_{{ forloop.counter }}">
      <div class="card card-body">
        {{text}}
      </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
<script>
  $('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var num = $(this).attr('id');
    var $collapse = $("#txt_" + num);
    // var $this = $(this);
    // var $collapse = $this.closest('.collapse-group').find('.collapse');
    $collapse.collapse('toggle');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: please debug with your own. add `console.log(num)` and `console.log($collapse)` after the variable and see what's going on

Comment: Opps you should add `id` in `div.collapse`, not in `card-body`. I will update my answer

Comment: problem still exist :-(

Comment: Do you set `console.log` in script? I'm not profession for javascript, so please debug with your own. Find out which value is null in your script

Comment: just checked, console.log(num);, is called more than once, and the button index is called many times to the desired value. 
for example I have 9 buttons, in the console I see a call 9 times with index 1, but then 8 times with index 2

Comment: did you move `{% endfor %}` out  of the script?

Comment: oh i dont,  now index is ok, try to console.log($collapse) and have jQuery.fn.init {}__proto__: Object(0)

Comment: Make sure that your `div.collapse` has correct id. And just try to execute your code in console. `var $collapse = $('#txt_1')` and `$collapse.collapse('toggle')`. let's see what happend

Comment: div collapse id is correct.  if you mean console.log($collapse = $('#txt_1')); , i have tha same output in console - jQuery.fn.init {}__proto__: Object(0)